# IE Browser Mode different from Document mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser-support

I am making a website for a client.

Tested it in Safari/IE9*8*7/Chrome/Firefox, everything fine.

I deliver the website and the client calls me that there are weird graphical stuff going on. I ask his browser version, check it on my pc('s) everything fine.

So I go over to the client, and it appears his browser Mode is IE9 and Document mode IE7 and that has some strange effects.

It seems it's the same on every PC in his office.

I have never seen an IE set like this. Is this common ? why do they do that ? Should I support that ?

If anyone has any answers, they are welcome :)

Comment: Can you force the document mode in the meta tags?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not accidentally triggering IE9 to render your page in older document mode and is actually overriding them to be the same on your own development machine? Certain doctypes and http headers combination (or meta http-equiv tag) could trigger IE9 to render the page in certain document mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these pages, they might be useful:

- [How Internet Explorer Chooses Between Document Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=vs.85%29)
- [X-UA-Compatibility Meta Tag and HTTP Response Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29)
- [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, not sure, but I think you can add this to the `<head>` part of your HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```